# Let $\{_\},\{_\}$ be given such that $_\leq _$, then if $\{_\}$ converges to $$ and $\{_\}$ to $$, show that $\leq $.

Tags: limits

> Let $\{_\}_{n\in\mathbb N},\{_\}_{n
> \in\mathbb N}$ be given such that for all $n$, $_\leq _$, then if $\{_\}$ converges to $$ and $\{_\}$ converges to $$, show that this implies $\leq $.

Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start. I tried applying the triangle inequality but did not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $c_n=b_n-a_n$. Clearly, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $c_n\in[0,\infty)$, a closed set. Closed sets contain their limit points, so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n\geq0$. Note that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n-a_n$$$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=b-a\geq0$$

Answer (score 0):

0) $c_n=b_n -a_n \ge 0$.

$c:= \lim c_n =b-a$.

Need to show $c \ge 0$.

1)Assume $c <0$;

$\epsilon >0$ given.

There exists a $n_0$ s.t. for $n \ge n_0$

$|c_n-c| <\epsilon$, i.e.

$-\epsilon + c < c_n< c+ \epsilon$.

Choose $\epsilon =-c/2 > 0$;

Then $c_n <c/2 <0$ for $n\ge n_0$;

Contradiction since $c_n=b_n-a_n \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Converging $c_n \to c$ means intuitively that the values of $c_n$s eventually get extremely close to $c$.  Formally we have a formal definition with $\epsilon$s (representing how close we can actually assure the $c_n$s get to $c$) and a $K$ (which represents how large the $n$s must be that *will* assure the $c_n$s are all within $\epsilon$ of the $c).

But intuitively the $b_n$s get close to $b$ and the $a_n$s get close to $a$ and each $an, b_n$ pair $a_n \le b_n$.  So must what the $a_n$s get close to by equal or less than what the $b_n$s get close to.  Is it possible for the $a_n$ to get close to something larger than what the $b_n$s get close to while the $a_n$ are all still equal or smaller than the $b_n$s?

Why not?  What if $a_n \to a$ and $b_n\to b$ but $b < a$?  What happens when $a_n$ is realllly realllly close to $a$ and $b_n$ is reallly reallly close to $b$ but $b < a$.  Can you picture that?  What if $a_n$ is just an iota away from $a$ and $b_n$ is just an iota away from $b$; what can we say about $a_n$ and $b_n$ in relations to each other.

Well.  $a_n$ is close to $a$ and $b_n$ is close to $b$ which is smaller than $a$ so $b_n$ must be smaller than $a_n$ and this contradicts that $a_n \le b_n$.

Can we formalize this?

> The formal definition is:  $a_n\to a$ means for any $\epsilon >0$ we can find a $K_{a}$ so that if $n > K_{a}$ then $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ and $b_n\to b$ means there is a $K_{b}$ so that if $n > K_b$ then $|b_n -b|< \epsilon$.

Our intuitive argument was that if $b < a$ then we can eventually get the distance between $a_n$ and $a$ and between $b_n$ and $b$ to be so small that $b_n < a_n$.  Now the distance between $a_n$ and $a$ and the distance between $b_n$ and $b$ is what $\epsilon$ represents. (Well, $\epsilon$ represents something bigger than the maximum possible distances.) And we want these distances to add up to less than the distance between $a$ and $b$.....

So.....

Proof by contradiction:

If $b < a$ then $a-b > 0$.  Let $\epsilon$ be such that $0 < \epsilon < \frac {a-b}2$.

$a_n\to a$ means there is an $K_a$ so that if $n > K$ that would mean $|a_n-a| < \epsilon$ and $b_n\to b$ means there is an $K_b$ so that if $n > K$ that would mean $|b_n-b| < \epsilon$.

So Let $n > K_a$ and $n > K_b$ (that is $n > \max(K_a,K_b)$) then $|a_n -a| < \epsilon< \frac {a-b} 2$ and $|b_n - b| < \epsilon< \frac {a-b}2$.

$|a_n-a| < \frac {a-b}2$ means $-\frac {a-b}2 < a_n -a < \frac {a-b}2$ so $\frac {a+ b}2 < a_n < \frac {3a -b}2$. And $|b_n - b| < \frac {a-b}2$ means $-\frac {a-b}2 < b_n - b < \frac {a-b}2$ so $\frac {3b-a}2 < b_n < \frac {a+b}2$.

And so $b_n < \frac {a+b}2 < a_n$ which is a contradiction.